# Rescaling Features for ML

Tags: clustering, feature-selection

I have data that is collected every month and I want to perform K-means clustering on each month (both on historical data and on future data). However, it isn't clear to me how best to rescale my data so that all of the features are comparable and that a feature can be easily compared across different months. The obvious thing to do is divide each column by the max of the corresponding column or normalize (i.e., subtract the mean and divide by the stddev). If I choose to divide by the max for a given month then I will end up with values between 0.0 and 1.0 but I won't be able to easily compare data between months if the max is different. For example:

Note: You can treat the following (single) feature as a list of players and the number of home runs that they have.

January => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

February => [1, 2, 3, 4, 100]

So, in player #1 had 1 homer in January and one in February. While, player #5 had 5 homers in January and 100 homers in February.

If I divide both data sets by their max then I get:

January => [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0]

February => [0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 1.0]

But then I'm not comparing the data from each month the same way. Alternatively, I could divide BOTH data sets by the global max (100) and get:

January => [0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05]

February => [0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 1.0]

This is what I'm currently doing but then some future month could look like this:

March => [1, 2, 3, 4, 10,000]

In other words, the future months could have a new max and significantly dominate my clustering. Again, this simple example shows a single feature but I can have hundreds of features that I'll have to rescale/normalize each month but I can't think of a good way to handle this. From what I understand, features should be rescaled so that they are within the same approximate scale (i.e., 2-5x within the same scale is okay according to Andrew Ng).

Perhaps another strategy is to try log scaling.

**Update** One commenter asked about standardizing the feature but, following the above example, the standardized monthly results look like this:

JAN => [-1.41, -0.71,  0.  ,  0.71,  1.41]

FEB => [-0.54, -0.51, -0.49, -0.46,  2.  ]

MAR => [-0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  2. ]

Notice that the number of home runs for player #1 is now uninterpretable (-1.41, -0.54, -0.5) even though this player has only one home run in each month. Conversely, player #3 had 10,000 home runs in March but it looks like he had as many home runs in February as well but that's not the case. Standardizing makes it very difficult to interpret and compare the data versus choosing a single normalization constant across all of the three months.

Comment: I didn't understand a few things; 1-) Why do you need a feature scaling in K-means? It seems to me at least global scaling doesn't change the result. 2-) How can you assume that a group of numbers is a single feature? 3-) Could you provide more information about what is your data and what is your features exactly. I couldn't get them from this post

Comment: I need feature scaling because K-means is using euclidean distance for clustering. My features could be percentages, counts, dollar amounts, etc (consider a baseball players with batting average, number of home runs, salary). Not scaling them would allow one feature to dominate the distance metric (i.e., weigh them disproportionately) while scaling would, hopefully, treat each feature with essentially the same/similar weight.

Comment: So, what is the drawback of the z-score (subtracting mean and divide by svd on each feature)?

Comment: It is difficult/impossible to interpret and compare values across each month. I've added the results of standardizing the monthly examples above.

Comment: The problem with k-means is that no matter how you scale the data, you will always have issues with outliers.  Using a log transform should work, but this may change the relationships between your variables considerably.  You may also want to take a look at k-medoids or other more robust classifiers.